# HTML assets get corrupted

Tags: javascript, html, webview

Does anyone know what might cause my HTML assets to get randomly corrupted when I use the application for an extended time? here is what it looks like.

[image]

Note: Not sure if it is important but we use webview to display the html and users have reported that assets sometimes randomly get corrupted and start looking fuzzy.

Comment: I personally have never seen anything like this before. How is it built?

Comment: Do you have any browser extensions?

Comment: Do you inspect element?

Comment: It is just an image tag actually. I do not have any extensions no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally found the reason that this happens. It turned out that this was happening because of the css filters.

These elements have filters that look something like this

```
filter: contrast(0.5) brightness(1.2);
```

and we even tried the vendor-specific prefix ones but yeah, these randomly corrupt the assets for some reason. Might be a bug in WebViews?